# Extracting data from API using grep

Tags: bash, web-scraping, xml-parsing

I'm trying to make a bash scraper, I've managed to extract the data, but struggle with fetching the lines for f.ex today's temperature using grep since the date and temperature is not on the same line. I would like the results to be outputted into a file.

I've tried grep -E -o '[2022]-[11]-[15]' | grep "celsius" | grep -E -o '[0-9]{1,2}.[0-9]{1,2}' > file.txt
API result

```
`product class="pointData">
<time datatype="forecast" from="2022-11-14T18:00:00Z" to="2022-11-14T18:00:00Z">
<location altitude="4" latitude="60.3913" longitude="5.3221">
<temperature id="TTT" unit="celsius" value="8.2"/>
<windDirection id="dd" deg="146.5" name="SE"/>
<windSpeed id="ff" mps="0.5" beaufort="1" name="Flau vind"/>
<windGust id="ff_gust" mps="1.2"/> 
<humidity unit="percent" value="82.5"/>
<pressure id="pr" unit="hPa" value="1014.5"/>
<cloudiness id="NN" percent="45.1"/> 
<fog id="FOG" percent="0.0"/>
<lowClouds id="LOW" percent="4.5"/>
<mediumClouds id="MEDIUM" percent="0.0"/>
<highClouds id="HIGH" percent="39.9"/>
<dewpointTemperature id="TD" unit="celsius" value="5.0"/>
</location>
</time>
<time datatype="forecast" from="2022-11-14T17:00:00Z" to="2022-11-14T18:00:00Z">
<location altitude="4" latitude="60.3913" longitude="5.3221">
<precipitation unit="mm" value="0.0" minvalue="0.0" maxvalue="0.0"/>
<symbol id="PartlyCloud" number="3" code="partlycloudy_night"/> 
</location>
</time>
<time datatype="forecast" from="2022-11-14T19:00:00Z" to="2022-11-14T19:00:00Z">
<location altitude="4" latitude="60.3913" longitude="5.3221"> 
<temperature id="TTT" unit="celsius" value="8.7"/>
<windDirection id="dd" deg="112.5" name="SE"/>
<windSpeed id="ff" mps="0.4" beaufort="1" name="Flau vind"/>
<windGust id="ff_gust" mps="0.8"/>
<humidity unit="percent" value="75.6"/>
<pressure id="pr" unit="hPa" value="1013.8"/>
<cloudiness id="NN" percent="57.5"/>
<fog id="FOG" percent="0.0"/>
<lowClouds id="LOW" percent="1.1"/>
<mediumClouds id="MEDIUM" percent="0.4"/>
<highClouds id="HIGH" percent="55.4"/>
<dewpointTemperature id="TD" unit="celsius" value="4.4"/>
</location>
</time>
```

Output to file should be.
8.2

Comment: what's the desired output?

Comment: Pardon, added  now. I want the result to be inputted into a text file I have.

Comment: Using grep for this is going to be very fragile. If you can use some sort of HTML parser tool, that's the way to go. Perhaps an XPath tool might work for you.

Comment: @Arawelo, hmmm... I don't see any updates. I see only the original html input (I think)...

Comment: @vgersh99 output to file should be 8.2 ( using the data from yesterday, since I copied the wrong part) :)

Comment: @Arawelo, hmm.. why not 8.7? They are both on `2022-11-14` (which is yesterday btw - not today).

Comment: `grep -A3 '2022-11-14' -m1 file.txt | grep -Po "celsius.*\K[0-9]{1,2}\.[0-9]{1,2}"` give 8.2

Comment: You added the "xml-parsing"-tag, so where's the XML-parser you're using? Please refrain from using tools that aren't meant to parse XML. With the XML-parser [tag:xidel] it would be as simple as: `xidel -s "<api-url>" -e '(//temperature)[1]/@value'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```bash
grep -A3 '2022-11-14' -m1 inputfile.txt | \
  grep -P -o "<temperature.*celsius.*\"\K\-?[0-9]{1,2}\.[0-9]{1,2}"
8.2
```

- **-A3** print 3 lines after match
- **-m1** Stop after first match
- **-P** use Perl regex
- **-o** grep only the match
- **\K** ignore what is before
- **-?** get - for negative temperature
- **[0-9]{1,2}.[0-9]{1,2}** the temperature in celsius

You can also use [xq](https://github.com/kislyuk/yq#xml-support):

```bash
$ date="2022-11-14"
$ xq -r '.product.time[0] | select (."@from" | contains("'$date'")) // null | '\
'.location|.temperature|(if ."@unit" == "celsius" then ."@value" else "error" end)' \
< input.html
8.2
```

Or as @AndyLester said, using xpath.

```bash
$ date="2022-11-14"
$ xmllint --xpath '//time[starts-with(@from,"'$date'")][1]'\
'//temperature[@unit="celsius"]/@value' input.txt  |\
grep -Po '[-]?\d+\.\d+'
```

Comment: The problem with this approach is that it's very fragile. If anything about the XML file changes, like the order of the tags changes, or maybe something else with `celsius` shows up in the top of the file, you'll get bad output. Worse, you may get bad output without knowing it. What if the `<dewpointTemperature>` tag and `<temperature>` tags swap positions? This greppy solution will now be giving incorrect results.

Comment: @AndyLester I edited the second regexg with `<temperature.*celsius` to prevent matching dewpointTemperature. But i agree grep isn't the best solution but since op ask for grep...

Comment: @AndyLester added xq and xpath. Celsius shows up before or tag swapping shouldn(t be an issue. Thx pointing that